# How to change content of order confirmation email template in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to change the content of order confirmation email template, only if a particular product has ordered. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the general template of email order confirmation in mails/language/order_conf.(html/txt).

The product list template in mails/languages/order_conf_product_list.(tpl/txt)

Called in classes/PaymentModule.php, validateOrder() function if you want to add variables.