# $total_paid get value Prestashop

Tags: php, oop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I'm confused. Try a lot of function/classes and nothing.

Please help my to understand in what file and function, `$total_paid` gets value?

The reason is why I need it, because I want to edit e-mail template `/mails/en/bankwire.html` at line:

```
<span style="color:#333"><strong>Amount:</strong></span> {total_paid}<br />
```

Thanks

UPD:

It's not duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367989/how-to-change-content-of-order-confirmation-email-template-in-prestashop) it's nearby but not exactly what I need. I post my question before see it. In my answer I will show more details of solving my question.

Comment: Thanks. But I think it's not exactly what I need. I explain it in my question and add more details in my answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I assumed a duplicate since you indicated that you'd found your answer there. I'll retract the close vote. Thanks for editing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For edit `$total_paid` variable I edit some code in `classes/PaymentModule.php` `function validateOrder()` which start at line 252 with:

```
foreach ($package_list as $id_address => $packageByAddress)
    foreach ($packageByAddress as $id_package => $package)
    {
        $order = new Order();
        $order->product_list = $package['product_list'];
```

…

And at line 321 I found this string:

```
$order->total_paid = $order->total_paid_tax_incl;
```

After line 321 I can change value for `$total_paid` by adding what I need to `$order->total_paid`

Thanks to Garry Cooper his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32382752/3629287) gave my a right direction for solve my question